# Robolectric with Android Annotations

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, robolectric, android-annotations

I use android-annotations in my projects and I start learning unit tests. I'm trying to execute tests with robolectric but with no success (Android Studio 8.6 and Gradle).
With some tutorials I configure my build.gradle and if I execute a simple test, without access any activity, the test generate OK results. But, when I try to execute tests accessing a activity, occurs errors.

Error

```
LoginActivityTest > testActivityAA2 FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException at LoginActivityTest.java:33
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at LoginActivityTest.java:33
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at LoginActivityTest.java:33
```

My Tests

```
@Config(manifest = "./src/main/AndroidManifest.xml", emulateSdk = 18)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class LoginActivityTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {

    //This is OK
    @Test
    public void testNumbers() throws Exception{
        final int expected = 5;
        final int reality = 5;
        assertEquals(expected, reality);
    }

    // this occurs error
    @Test
    public void testActivityAA2() throws Exception {
        LoginActivity_ loginnActivity = new LoginActivity_();
        loginnActivity.onCreate(null);
        assertNotNull(loginnActivity);
    }
}
```

My build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '3.0.1'
apply plugin: 'robolectric'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        // replace with the current version of the Android plugin
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12+'
        // the latest version of the android-apt plugin
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.3'
        classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:0.11.+'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {

    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'

    // Espresso
    androidTestCompile files('lib/espresso-1.1.jar', 'lib/testrunner-1.1.jar', 'lib/testrunner-runtime-1.1.jar')
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'

    androidTestCompile('junit:junit:4.11') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    androidTestCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3') {
        exclude module: 'classworlds'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
        exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
        exclude module: 'maven-model'
        exclude module: 'maven-project'
        exclude module: 'maven-settings'
        exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
        exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
        exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
        exclude module: 'wagon-file'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
        exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'
}

apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        testOutputDir = file('build/test-classes/debug')
    }
}

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName 'com.example.project'

        // If you're using Android NBS flavors you should use the following line instead of hard-coded packageName
        // resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.packageName

        // You can set optional annotation processing options here, like these commented options:
        // logLevel 'INFO'
        // logFile '/var/log/aa.log'
    }
}

robolectric {
    include '**/*Test.class'
    exclude '**/espresso/**/*.class'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.nexxcity.nexxcitypos"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            setRoot('src/androidTest')
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me guys ? 
Thx for patience

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't initialise the Activity like that for Robolectric tests. 
Use Robolectric.buildActivity() (documentation: http://robolectric.org/activity-lifecycle/)

For example: 
Robolectric.buildActivity(LoginActivity.class).create().get()

Depending on what you need to test, you can chain additional methods as well like visible(), start() etc.

Comment: Thx for the help. Just this dont resolve the problem. But I solved, I follow this tutorial (http://www.peterfriese.de/android-testing-with-robolectric/), created a custom test runner, and solved the problem. Thx man =)

Comment: I have the same problem. When I use android annotation it always return null for findViewById(). And Robolectric.buildActivity(LoginActivity.class).create().get()  gives me TargetInvocation exception